# Div vertically align

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have three `<div>` like this:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 ">
                    <img src="custom_images/logo3.png" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-center">
                    <div class="input-group">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control header_search" placeholder="Search Here....." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
                        <span class="input-group-addon search_span" id="basic-addon1" ><i class="fa fa-search "></i> </span>
                    </div>
                    <%--<div class="">
                        <input type="search" placeholder="Search Here...." />
                        <span style="background-color:#000;padding:10px;">
                            <img src="custom_images/search.png" /></span>
                    </div>--%>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-right">
                    <button class="cart_button"><span>Items in your cart</span> <span style="margin-left:25px;"><img src="custom_images/cart_item.png" /></span></button>
                    <span class="cart_items">15</span>

                </div>
```

I am not able to **vertically align** them in a line. I want all of them to be like `vertically-align: middle`.

Here is how it looks right now:

[image]

Please help me into this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [vertical alignment of elements in a div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79461/vertical-alignment-of-elements-in-a-div)

Comment: @Jivings Nopes, not related.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you give the parent element the following CSS, you should be fine:

```
element{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: it worked fine....yet the editor shows that the properties are not valid css properties....may be this would be removed in future....

Comment: Oh it won't be removed in the future. It is brand new, that's why the editor doesn't know the properties. It is valid, just new.

Comment: using display flex creates problem for the responsive....it shows the horizontal scroll bar...

Comment: If you make a Fiddle, I can try and solve that for you

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the logo is of fixed height. You can use `margin-top` on the top `<div>` using this:

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-center adjust-top-height">
  <div class="input-group">
    <input type="text" class="form-control header_search" placeholder="Search Here....." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
    <span class="input-group-addon search_span" id="basic-addon1" ><i class="fa fa-search "></i> </span>
  </div>
  <div class="">
    <input type="search" placeholder="Search Here...." />
    <span style="background-color:#000;padding:10px;">
      <img src="custom_images/search.png" /></span>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-right adjust-top-height">
  <button class="cart_button"><span>Items in your cart</span> <span style="margin-left:25px;"><img src="custom_images/cart_item.png" /></span></button>
  <span class="cart_items">15</span>
</div>
```

And in the CSS

```
.adjust-top-height {margin-top: 15px;}
```

Comment: yea thanks...but i that is a kind of adjustment. i want it to be perfect even if the height of the logo changes in future. so i may not be worried about it..

Comment: @SohilShah Sure... Okay, then the accepted answer is perfect. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div class="header">    
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 header-element">
      <img src="custom_images/logo3.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-center  header-element">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control header_search" placeholder="Search Here....." aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        <span class="input-group-addon search_span" id="basic-addon1"><i class="fa fa-search "></i> </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4 text-right">
      <button class="cart_button"><span>Items in your cart</span> <span style="margin-left:25px;"><img src="custom_images/cart_item.png" /></span></button>
      <span class="cart_items">15</span>

    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header-element{
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```